# How to get Lead Owner profile from Trigger

Tags: trigger, profile, leads, ownership

I am looking for a solution to get the Lead Owner profile name from Trigger.new , instead of doing a seperate query  on "User" record to get the profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that. The trigger has all the direct fields of the object but not those available through relationships.

You will need to do a query for those, you should make sure you do this in a bulked way so that you only use one SOQL query no matter how many Leads are being handled by the trigger.